# Pyspark- equivalent of explode for splitting in to columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in a dataframe that contains an array. I want to convert this array in to columns

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, intlist=DenseVector([1,2,3])), Row(a=2, intlist=DenseVector([4,5,6]))])
>>> df.show()
+---+-------------+
|  a|      intlist|
+---+-------------+
|  1|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|
|  2|[4.0,5.0,6.0]|
+---+-------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| a| _1| _2|  _3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  2|  3|
|  2|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+---+
```

The `explode` function can do this but it adds rows instead of columns

```
>>> df.select(explode(df.intlist).alias("anInt")).show()
+-----+
|anInt|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
+-----+
```

Is there a way we can add columns instead of rows?

Comment: How does column `a` turn into `_1`? And for your question, why not just use `df.select`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele corrected the renaming. `df.select`? how, do you mean?

Comment: @user6910411 is it advisable to go back an forth between an `rdd` and a `dataframe`? Performance wise.

Comment: Both RDDs and UDFs are expensive here, but since you have `Vector` (not `array`), you won't be able to access this data otherwise in PySpark.